# Configure Debezium CDC -> Kafka -> JDBC Sink (Multiple tables) Question

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

We have around 100 tables in SQL server DB(Application DB) which needs to be synced to SQL server DB(for Analytics) in near Realtime.

Future use case: Scale the Proof of Concept for 30 Source DBs to one destination DB(for Analytics) in near Realtime.

I am thinking to use one sink connector or few sink connectors for multiple tables. Please let me know if this is a good idea.

But I am not sure how to configure the sink to cater for multiple tables especially that each table might have its own primary key. Internet seems to have very simple examples of sink connector but not addressing complex use cases.

Debezium CDC(Source) config

```
  {  "name": "wwi",
    "config": {
     "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.sqlserver.SqlServerConnector",
  "database.dbname": "************************",
  "database.history": "io.debezium.relational.history.MemoryDatabaseHistory",
  "database.hostname": "**********************",
  "database.password": "**********************",
  "database.port": "1433",
  "database.server.name": "******",
  "database.user": "*********",
  "decimal.handling.mode": "string",
  "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
  "key.converter.schemas.enable": "true",
  "snapshot.mode": "schema_only",
  "table.include.list": "Sales.Orders,Warehouse.StockItems",
  "tasks.max": "1",
  "tombstones.on.delete": "false",
  "transforms": "route,unwrap",
  "transforms.route.regex": "([^.]+)\\.([^.]+)\\.([^.]+)",
  "transforms.route.replacement": "$3",
  "transforms.route.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.RegexRouter",
  "transforms.unwrap.type": "io.debezium.transforms.ExtractNewRecordState",
  "value.converter.schemas.enable": "true",
  "value.convertor": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter"
    }
    }
```

JDBC Sink config

```
{
    "name": "sqlsinkcon",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
        "topics": "orders",
        "tasks.max": "1",
        "auto.evolve": "true",
        "connection.user": "********",
        "auto.create": "true",
        "connection.url": "jdbc:sqlserver://************",
        "insert.mode": "upsert",
        "pk.mode":"record_key",
        "pk.fields":"OrderID",
        "db.name": "kafkadestination"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The sink will write one table, per consumed topic. `topics` or `topics.regex` can be used to consume multiple topics at once.

Regarding scalability (or at least, fault tolerance), I prefer one sink task, with one topic (therefore writing to one table). Otherwise, if you consume multiple topics, and connector fails, then it'll potentially crash all the task threads due to the consumer rebalancing.

Also, using JSON / plaintext formats in Kafka isn't most optimal in terms of network bandwidth. I'd suggest a binary format like Avro or Protobuf.

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation. Can you please let me know what you think of having 100 sink connectors (each for one table)? Any suggestion to maintain/monitor these many connectors ?

Comment: I've used datadog before on more S3 sink connectors than that, but Prometheus+Grafana would work too.